# Static member function

Tags: c++, function, static-methods

I understand why static functions can't access non-static fields.
But if I send them an object of the class, will they be able to access his private fields? (not static)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How hard would it be to try it yourself?

Comment: look i have a test tomorrow and would like some quick answers

Comment: Interesting issue with regards to the way this site works.  Anything more than four characters in the answer is just excessive verbiage.  But the site won't let you post an answer with just four characters.

Comment: You might wonder - if the function needs access to the private fields, why was it made static in the first place?

Comment: @dlv please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. You're expected to a minimum of research before asking, that's why you got downvoted.

Comment: But it our lectures it says: Static member functions may access only static data members. I tried to access a non static field and it worked. So how can it work? If the function is static who's field is it accessing? If the field is not static then it belongs to a specific object..

Comment: @JamesKanze Read The Fine Manual?

Comment: In static method you have no access to this. How would you access private members of an instance?

Comment: @Spook Through another pointer or reference.

Comment: @div You're lecturer is wrong.  The only difference between a static member function and a non-static one is that the static function doesn't have a `this` pointer (which in turn means that it can be called without an object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they will. Here is a short sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    A(): a(0) {}
    static void test(A& x) {
        x.a += 1;
    }
    private:
    int a;
};
int main() {
        A u;
    A::test(u);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiled on [ideone](http://ideone.com/41jRHE). You should **really** learn to try such things on your own.

Comment: But it our lectures it says: Static member functions may access only static data members. I tried and it works. So how can it work? If the function is static who's field is it accessing? If the field is not static then it belongs to a specific object..

Comment: Here you access a member of an **argument**. Static functions can do whatever they want with their arguments. Problem is they have no access with instance members because there is **no instance** associated with them.

Comment: I did not try to access a member of an arguement.
I accessed an actual field of the class..

Comment: @div show us an example of what you did. What you say can not work.

Comment: SongStructure Song::removeVerseChorus(SongStructure original,
  int indexOfVerse) {
 name="dlv";
}
And this is a static function.. how can it access name (which is not static)?

Comment: @dlv Put it in your original question, properly formatted, also with an example on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every member function can access private members (fields or methods) of their class, whether they're static or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
E.g.:

```
class objType
{
    static void f(objType &obj);
    ...
    void f(objType &obj)
    {
        obj.somePrivateMember...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Access rights and whether a function is static or not are
orthogonal concepts.  A member function can access all members,
private, protected or public.  Regardless of whether it is
static or not.  A static member function has no `this` pointer,
however, and non-static members require an object in order to be
accessed (or even to exist).  So if the static function is to
access non-static members, it must obtain a pointer or
a reference to another object (or create one as a local
variable, but this is really rare).  So:

```
class Test
{
    int i;              //  Non-static member...
    static int si;      //  Static member...
public:
    static void func( Test* obj );
};

void
Test::func( Test* obj )
{
    si = 1;             //  No problem.
    i = 1;              //  Illegal, no instance.
    obj->i = 1;         //  No problem.
}
```

(Obviously, in a trivial case like this, you'd just drop the
static on `func`, and use `this` instead of `obj`.  But one can
imagine other ways of obtaining a pointer to an instance in the
static function.)